# Differentiation under Integral Sign involving an Exponential

Tags: integration, derivatives, exponential-function

An economics paper that I am reading has this expression:
$Q_{t} = \int_{t}^{\infty}\delta e^{-(\bar{r}+\delta)(s-t)-\int_{t}^{s}\pi_{u}du}ds$. After taking derivative with respect to time, the above relationship changes to
$Q_{t}(\bar{r} + \delta + \pi_{t}) = \delta + \dot{Q_{t}}$
where the dot over $Q_{t}$ refers to time derivative. I am trying to go from the first expression to the second one but I can't seem to get it right. Can you please help?

Here is what I did:

$\frac{d}{dt}Q_{t} = \dot{Q_{t}} = \int_{t}^{\infty}\frac{d}{dt}[\delta e^{-(\bar{r}+\delta)(s-t)-\int_{t}^{s}\pi_{u}du}]ds \Rightarrow
\dot{Q_{t}} = \int_{t}^{\infty}\delta e ^{-(\bar{r}+\delta)(s-t)-(\pi_{s} - \pi_{t})}ds \cdot (\bar{r}+\delta+\frac{d}{dt}(\pi_{t}))
= Q_{t}(\bar{r}+\delta+\frac{d}{dt}(\pi_{t}))$

This, of course, is not what the paper has. Will appreciate any help.

Comment: Your second equality isn't correct, because the limits of (the outer) integration also depend on $t$. You need a second term added to that expression, which (by the fundamental theorem of calculus) is negative of the integrand with $s$ set equal to $t$.

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks. I see it a little bit. I still could not figure it out. Any chance, you could show it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for showing your work—it makes it easy to help out!

There are two mistakes in your derivation. The first is the one I mentioned in my comment. If we have a function of the form $G(t) = \int_t^\infty f(s,t)\,ds$, then the formula for the derivative is that $G'(t) = -f(t,t) + \int_t^\infty \frac\partial{\partial t}f(s,t)$. (Mnemonic, which can be turned into a proof: if $t$ appears multiple times in the definition of a function, then the function's $t$-derivative is the sum of all the derivatives you get by considering each $t$ in turn, pretending all the other $t$s are actually constant, and taking the derivative of the function-with-just-that-one-variable-$t$. If you think about it, that's exactly what the product rule formula does—and even the formula for $t^n = t\times\cdots\times t$ works right under this mnemonic!) In this case, that tells us that
\begin{align*}
\dot Q_t &= -\delta e^{-(\bar r+\delta)(t-t)-\int_t^t \pi_u\,du} + \int_t^\infty \frac\partial{\partial t} \big[ \delta e^{-(\bar r+\delta)(s-t)-\int_t^s \pi_u\,du} \big] \,ds \\
&= -\delta + Q_t \frac\partial{\partial t} \bigg[ {-}(\bar r+\delta)(s-t)-\int_t^s \pi_u\,du \bigg].
\end{align*}
The second mistake is that you wrote $\int_t^s \pi_u\,du = \pi_s-\pi_t$ (it would be the case that $\int_t^s \frac d{du}(\pi_u)\,du = \pi_s-\pi_t$, but that's not what we have), which caused an error in your evaluation of $\frac\partial{\partial t} \big[ {-}(\bar r+\delta)(s-t)-\int_t^s \pi_u\,du \big]$. We actually get
$$
\frac\partial{\partial t} \bigg[ {-}(\bar r+\delta)(s-t)-\int_t^s \pi_u\,du \bigg] = \bar r+\delta + \pi_t,
$$
which plugs into the above equation to yield
$$
\dot Q_t = -\delta + Q_t(\bar r+\delta + \pi_t)
$$
as desired.

Comment: Really appreciate it, Greg. When you write $G^{\prime}(t) = -f(t,t) + \int_{t}^{\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(s,t)$, are you using Leibniz's rule for differentiation under integral sign? I looked up the formula on the internet and it looked different everywhere. And time derivative of the power yields $\bar{r} + \delta + \pi_{t}$. Is it because $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}[\int_{t}^{s}\pi_{u}\mathrm{d}u] = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}[\frac{\pi_{u}^{2}}{2}]_{t}^{s} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}[\frac{\pi_{s}^{2}}{2}-\frac{\pi_{t}^{2}}{2}] = -\pi_{t}$? Just want to understand better.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule). No, the integral of $\pi_u$ is not $\frac12\pi_u^2$, because $\pi_u$ is an unknown function of $u$; finding the derivative of that integral is simply the [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part), which actually follows from the Leibniz rule.

Comment: Hi @GregMartin, sorry for asking something I should already know -- you said the integral of $\pi_{u}$ is not $\frac{1}{2}\pi_{u}^{2}$ because it's an unknown function of $u$. So what exactly is its integral? And why is any different from the cases in which, for example, when we integrate $x_{t}$, we end up with $\frac{1}{2}x_{t}^{2}$?

Comment: I think the notation $\pi_u$ is confusing. If it were written explicitly as a function, $\pi(u)$, then you wouldn't think that its antiderivative should be $\frac12\pi(u)^2$, because that's not how functions work. (Same comment for $x_t$.) What is the derivative of $\frac12\pi_u^2$ with respect to $u$? By the chain rule, it's $\pi_u\cdot \frac d{du}\pi_u$, which is not the same as $\pi_u$; therefore $\frac12\pi_u^2$ can't be the integral of $\pi_u$ with respect to $u$.